# Ищу решение вывести в случайном порядке посты в категории wp?

Tags: wordpress

Был предложен такой код:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rand_category' );
function rand_category( $query ) {
    if( is_category() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
}
```

Рэндом работает, но ошибка в том что посты в категории стали дублироваться по два три раза, т.е. происходит замена, количество постов в категории не увеличивается, остается прежним. Может можно дописать? Хозяйка кода не отвечает((, может не видела моё сообщение, причину не знаю... И можно к конкретной категории применить?